# purpose of comparing pointer with (unsigned) -4000L

Tags: c, pointers

In open source component, [cjson](https://github.com/openwebos/cjson/blob/43de024867b8d38f607f04cfede8608ce532a8e6/bits.h#L26),

`#define is_error(ptr) ((unsigned long)ptr > (unsigned long)-4000L)`

Above statement is used to check the validity of pointer as shown below

```
json_object* reply = json_object_new_object();
if (!reply || is_error(reply))
{
 . . . //error handling
}
```

How does comparing pointer with `(unsigned long)-4000L` validates pointer?

Comment: Maybe that is how json functions work and return exit-codes.

Comment: Version 0.3 mentions "fix pointer arithmetic bug for error pointer check in is_error() macro", see https://github.com/openwebos/cjson/blob/43de024867b8d38f607f04cfede8608ce532a8e6/ChangeLog#L45. That doesn't explain it though.

Comment: What a horrible api design. Makes you wonder what other "gems" they have put in...

Comment: As Wumpus Q Wumbley says, this isn't uncommon, although more in operating systems than user code. See also tagged pointers, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer

Comment: @Joe Might be acceptable to OS code, but not really on JSON parser. `json_object * json_object_new_object(int * optionalErrorCode)` would have been a lot better.

Comment: There is at least an error lurking in the macrodefinition, ptr should have been parenthesised: `#define is_error(ptr) ((unsigned long)(ptr) > (unsigned long)-4000L)` , to avoid problems when invoked like `is_error(reply+42)` ... For the rest: it is an implementation issue.

Comment: @user694733 I agree. They could spare an extra field in a struct, it's only a JSON parser.

Comment: @joop you should probably raise a defect on the github project.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this looks like they're using the pointer value to contain "either a pointer or an error value".

[Look here](https://github.com/openwebos/cjson/blob/43de024867b8d38f607f04cfede8608ce532a8e6/json_tokener.c#L93):

```
struct json_object* json_tokener_parse(const char *str)
{
  struct json_tokener* tok;
  struct json_object* obj;

  tok = json_tokener_new();
  obj = json_tokener_parse_ex(tok, str, -1);
  if(tok->err != json_tokener_success)
    obj = error_ptr(-tok->err); // <<<<<---
  json_tokener_free(tok);
  return obj;
}
```

The function is returning a special value as a pointer. The [`err_ptr` macro](https://github.com/openwebos/cjson/blob/43de024867b8d38f607f04cfede8608ce532a8e6/bits.h#L25) returns the negative of the error code, presumably because the author assumes this will never be a valid pointer address.

[Here is a test](https://github.com/openwebos/cjson/blob/43de024867b8d38f607f04cfede8608ce532a8e6/test1.c#L138) that demonstrates the expected usage of the macro, i.e. malformed JSON.

```
 new_obj = json_tokener_parse("{ foo }");
  if(is_error(new_obj)) printf("got error as expected\n");
```

So, the reason for using that special value is so they can hold "either a pointer to a structure or an error code". This could also be done with a union or a struct, or by some other means, but they chose to do it this way.

Comment: Linux does something very similar inside the kernel, which may be where these json people got the idea. The kernel has to know the pointer format of all supported architectures anyway, so it can guarantee that this trick works.

Answer (score 0):

It look likes the author is making platform-specific assumptions about where virtual memory will be allocated.  In this case the assumption is that a valid pointer will always be in within roughtly the first 4GB of addressable space *[edit: that's onthe (dubious) assumption that `long` is 32-bit.]*

Your particular example seems to come from a thing called OpenWebOS.  I don't know what that is; but if they are the makers of the Operating System, then they get to make up their own rules about where the pointers will go.  Perhaps that OS even has a convention that addresses above a certain value are used to signal errors.

If you want to write portable code, you should think hard before trying tricks like this.

Comment: How did you make out "4GB address space"?

Comment: I was wrong, I thought that on most modern systems (even 64-bit ones), that `long` was 32-bits.  In which case `(unsigned long)-4000` is roughly 4G.  However `long` can be 64 bits on some quite common systems.  In which case it is roughly 16 EB.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't, except in some very specific cases - maybe the original author had a pointer bug where his pointers were corrupted in a way that they got in the "range" of this comparison, or his compiler and operating system have some strange non-standard pointer validation or interpretation "features".

-4000 interpreted as an unsigned 32-bit integer is 0xfffff060.

If it were code running in kernel, it *mighy* have something to do with the userland / kernel memory space divide (i.e. top half vs bottom half of the address space), but even then it would probably be wrong. My money is on the first idea.

Comment: Why 32-bit integer? The source says `-4000L`.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Since it is a negative value, just add "ff"s in front. As a 64-bit unsigned int, it is 0xfffffffffffff060.

Answer (score 0):

wrong check! There should not be any such value like  (unsigned long)-4000L). It should be either a NULL (not allocated) or non-NULL (having valid value). Whenever the pointer gets deallocated, it should be reverted back to NULL, I mean re-assign to NULL to avoid dangling pointer. A value of non-NULL check is enough to know the pointer is valid and pointing to some valid content.

Comment: The question isn't "should I?" but "why did they?".